# Where are the sharepoint 2010 client assemblies

Tags: csom

I am wondering where I am able to download the sharepoint 2010 client assemblies (the ones located in folder 14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **SharePoint 2010**: You can either get them from a SharePoint installation (`C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI`) or download at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21786.
- **SharePoint 2013**: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI` or download at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585.

Comment: that download isn't working for me? it doesn't put any files in the ISAPI

Comment: The point of this download is not to put the assemblies into an existing SharePoint installation. It's only to give you these client DLLs, so you can develop client tools targeting (remotely) SharePoint data (after setup, the client DLLs are available in VS to be added as references in your project).

Comment: Also: maybe the confusion is you're working on SP2013: in thaht case the "14\ISAPI" folder is quite empty, and you should look at "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI" instead. Also, the download link for 2013 version of the client DLLs is at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585. Updated my anwser.

Comment: nope defo on 2010

Answer (score 2):

For SharePoint 2010, check in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\SharePoint Client\

Answer (score 0):

- If you’re developing a managed .NET client application—for example, a WPF application—you need to add references to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll. You can find them in the `14\ISAPI` folder on your SharePoint server.
- If you’re developing a Silverlight application, you need to add references to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.Runtime.dll. You can find them in the `14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ClientBin` folder on your SharePoint server.
- If you’re writing JavaScript code, you can find SP.js and all the other SharePoint JavaScript libraries in the `14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS` folder.

Comment: and where can I download these? 14\ISAPI ones?

Comment: @jimmybigshoes..go to the server where sharepoint is installed and then navigate to "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI"